# plot accuracy of classification in Random forest and SVM in R

Tags: data-visualization, svm, random-forest, accuracy

I have a question and I will be grateful if you help me.
 Is it possible to plot admixture or pure of individuals with Random forest-SVM methods (models) in R . Is there command for this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can plot ROC curves to plot Area under curve of two models to compare their performances.

Look for library(pROC)

Comment: I perform it. But I want to plot like plot admixture software.